# What are the most written/read languages on the internet?

Tags: translation

I'm developing a large chat application; the public beta had over sixty-five thousand participants, so I need the final version to be complete. Hence I am asking this question.  My application needs to work in all the languages that I can expect my visitors to see it in. I want to cover (most) of the written/read languages of countries ***that have internet***.

With some research; I've compiled the following list: (In the order I should prioritize translating my application into it. **Bold** indicates a completed translation.)

- **English**
- **Japanese**
- **Lithuanian**
- Chinese (Vernacular?)
- Spanish
- Portuguese
- Arabic
- Hindi
- Indonesian (?)
- Russian
- German

Comment: Totally off-topic. This would be *maybe* on-topic for Linguistics.

Comment: @JSBᾶngs You have ~3k Rep, why not move the topic?  I can't (obviously).

Comment: I'm not sure this question is on topic here, either. Let's see what other users have to say...

Comment: @OtavioMacedo I'm kind of agreeing with you.

Comment: @Alenanno Seems to have been on topic enough.

Comment: maybe programmers.SE?

Comment: @cbroughton We still aren't on a safe side regarding what is on topic and what is not. This question is a bit ambiguous to me, that's why I didn't close it right away.

Comment: Well, is that any better?

Comment: Are you looking to have labels and menu options translated to the various top languages? or do you want to allow other writing/displaying methods (right-to-left, russian/greek/korean/devanagari, arabic/hebrew, chinese/japanese)?

Comment: It's an interesting question but not a linguistics question. It's about demographics, Internet, languages, and quite possibly internationalization and/or localization. I would suggest asking it as an example question on the new [I18N & L10N proposal on Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12416/i18n-l10n) whether or not it stays open here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds to me like what you really need to understand is: which language will the *likely users* of your application be using?

As a starting point, here's a list of the most common languages used online:

http://www.internetworldstats.com/stats7.htm

(The design may be horrible, but the data seems pretty legitimate).

Additionally, [this report](http://www.bcg.com/documents/file58645.pdf) lists the countries with the greatest engagement with instant messaging:

[image]

Chinese - topping both lists - should be your priority. The language used online in China is [vernacular written Chinese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Written_vernacular_Chinese) (based on Mandarin). It would be very unusual to see 'Traditional Chinese' in a web interface.

Although India is #2 in IM use, the majority of Indian web user's use English. Hindi is still rare online ([source](http://books.google.com/books?id=wSlOkuwWKo4C&pg=PA150#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

Thus, I would suggest Portuguese and Spanish as your next priority, to capture a large section of the South American user-base (as well as a portion of European users).

Russian and Arabic - which has seen the largest growth in internet usage over the past decade ([source](http://www.scottmclay.co.uk/foreign-language-internet-good-business/)) - German, Japanese would all be valid additions.

Incidentally, if you're translating common UI elements, take a look at the [Pootle Terminology](http://pootle.locamotion.org/projects/terminology/) project, and [Microsoft's UI translations](http://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Translations.aspx).

Comment: Luckily, I am blessed with connections enough to have my UI translated frequently (in parts) during the development of my application by native language speakers (with the exception of a few ... "different" languages.)  Would you say that the languages I have listed are sufficient?

Comment: Don't forget the North American Spanish speaking user-base - the biggest Spanish speaking country in the world is there!

Answer (score 1):

For users outside of Europe, I'd add French and Malay.

Comment: @MarkBeadles admittedly it is a substandard answer, but it's not a comment or request for clarification; it attempts to answer the question by suggesting languages other than those already named in the question.

Comment: Fair enough! :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Alex Peattie: # of websites in a language does not always correlate with # of users of software in the language. Having said that, http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2011/07/languages-of-world-wide-web.html might give you some ideas about what languages are most popular online. The data is from Google's researchers, and so, ought to be trustworthy.